# What is the difference between Lehmann-Kallen and Dispersion relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, dispersion

I know that the Lehmann-Kallen (LK) form of an operator concerns just that, an operator. But the LK is very similar in form to dispersion relations found in analytic S-matrix theory.